# Where are the replicator page settings stored in Lotus Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes

I want a clean slate in the Notes 8.5.3 client, but I do not want to wipe out the notes.ini and go through a fresh setup. What else, besides deleting the cache, desktop, and bookmark files should I do in order to clear the Replication and Synch page?

Background:  I've got a case where attempting to open a local replica of a database in my Lotus Notes 8.5.3 client is causing the client to open a server replica instead. The icons are stacked on the desktop, and even though I select the local replica through the File - Open - IBM Notes Application menu, the server replica pops back to the top of the stack.

Obviously, something is corrupt.

I've deleted the cache, desktop, and bookmarks files in the Data folder, but when I go to the Replication & Sync page in the client, though, all the previous entries are still there - and the icons repopulate on the workspace page.

Answer (score 2):

It is partly stored in the location document within your personal addressbook. Remove / rename names.nsf to get rid of this or create a new location document.

Comment: I created a new Location doc from scratch, and switched to it.  Although the checkmarks next to all the icons representing NSF files were removed, the icons remained. What I haven't tried yet is another round of deleting cache, desktop and bookmarks combined with this new location. But I also seem to have solved my problem with opening the local replica by deleting it and pulling a new one.  The one I had pulled must not have been fully initialized, which caused the client to go searching for a server-based replica. Now that I have a good replica, it doesn't matter that the icons are stacked.